# Case when exists - column (SQL)

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to populate the field of an XML file with either '0', if a specific column (pv_an4) does not exist, OR with the value of the column, if it exists.

This is my code so far:

```
XMLELEMENT( Name "Telephone",
case
when not exists (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'phonebook' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'pv_an4') then ''
when exists (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'phonebook' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'pv_an4') then pv_an4
end ),
```

When I execute this I get this error:

> FEHLER:  Column »pv_an4« does not exist ZEILE 25: ...E_NAME =
>   'phonebook' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'pv_an4') then pv_an4

But this does make no sense to me, because for example with this code it would work:

```
....

when exists (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'phonebook' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'pv_an4') then 'pv_an4 exists'
end ),

....
```

I've spent the whole day trying to solve this problem, could someone hint me in the right direction, please?

/edit: Full query right below:

```
    SELECT
XMLFOREST( xmlpb.entry as "DivinusIPPhoneDirectory" )
FROM (
SELECT
XMLCONCAT (
XMLELEMENT ( NAME "Title", 'Phonelist' ),
XMLELEMENT ( NAME "Prompt", 'Prompt' ),
XMLAGG (
XMLELEMENT (
NAME "DirectoryEntry",
XMLELEMENT( Name "Name",
case
when (pb.company = '') IS FALSE AND pb.lastname != '' and pb.firstname != '' then pb.company || ' - ' || pb.lastname || ', ' || pb.firstname
when (pb.company = '') IS FALSE AND pb.lastname != '' and pb.firstname = '' then pb.company || ' - ' || pb.lastname
when (pb.company = '') IS FALSE AND pb.lastname = '' and pb.firstname = '' then pb.company
when (pb.company = '') IS FALSE AND pb.lastname = '' and pb.firstname != '' then pb.company || ' - ' || pb.firstname
when (pb.company = '') IS NOT FALSE AND pb.lastname != '' and pb.firstname != '' then pb.lastname || ', ' || pb.firstname
when (pb.company = '') IS NOT FALSE AND  pb.lastname != '' and pb.firstname = '' then pb.lastname
end ),
XMLELEMENT( Name "Telephone", pb.pv_an3 ),
XMLELEMENT( Name "Telephone",
case
when not exists (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'phonebook' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'pv_an4') then ''
else pb.pv_an4
end ),
XMLELEMENT( Name "Telephone", pb.phonenumber ),
XMLELEMENT( Name "Telephone", pb.pv_an1 ),
XMLELEMENT( Name "Telephone", pb.pv_an2 )
)
)
) as entry
FROM
phonebook pb
WHERE fkidtenant = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole sql statement is parsed and compiled **before** it is run, therefore postgresql will complain of the missing field. There is no shortcut.

You need to use dynamically generated sql if you want to handle such scenarios (check whether the column exists and create the appropriate sql statement). Although I cannot really imagine why you should not know if a certain column exists in a table or not.

Comment: I am having different versions of a table. One has the specified field, another does not. Thats why I need to check if it exists, otherwise the query fails because the column does not exist..

Comment: As you can see, the query fails anyway because of the missing column. There is no shortcut, you must know what columns a table has before querying it.

Comment: Ok thank you, didn't know the sql statement is parsed and compiled before it is run..  I'd dive into dynamically generated sql.. Maybe this helps me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
XMLELEMENT( Name "Telephone",
case
when not exists (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME   = 'phonebook' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'pv_an4') then ''
when exists (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'phonebook' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'pv_an4') then 'pv_an4'
end ),
```

In line 4, you're using pv_an4 as a column in your first query, but as a column value in your second query.

Comment: Thats because I want to use the columns value, if the column exists. If the column does not exist, I would like to have the result of the case empty.

Comment: Post your full query. You're using `pv_an4`, but not of the table `phonebook`, so that may be the confusion.

Comment: @RudyM the OP does not know if a certain column exists in a table or not and would like to handle this directly in the select. Already told him that this is a no go.